# Bring text in div with overlay to front so opacity doesn't affect text color?

Tags: html, css

I apologize for poor wording, so I've included the timer I'm working on. Is it possible to hack this so the text is still on top of the overlay and not darkened by it? Be sure to open in full screen or the white will blend.

If it is not I can consider re-nesting, but not sure how I could achieve the same results without the overlay covering the text. I've looked at a few similar examples, but can't isolate precisely how they were able to keep the white text unaffected by the opacity while allowing the elements to remain inside the Div.

```css
#countdown-overlay {
  background: url('https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/spiration-dark.png');
  opacity: .8;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#countdown {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #673AB7;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #512DA8, #673AB7);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #512DA8, #673AB7);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.counter-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 250;
  text-align: center;
}

#timer {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.clock-border {
  display: table;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.value {
  font-size: 200%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="countdown">
  <div id="countdown-overlay">
    <h1 class="counter-title"> Next stream in</h1>

    <div id="timer">
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">4 Days</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">7 Hours</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">3 Min</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">24 Sec</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>



</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `opacity` from div and add `before`.
Give `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);` to the *pseudo-element*  and a `z-index`

```css
#countdown-overlay {
  background: url('https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/spiration-dark.png');
 /* opacity: .8;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
/**Add before */
#countdown-overlay:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(169, 161, 186, 0.38);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#countdown {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #673AB7;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #512DA8, #673AB7);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #512DA8, #673AB7);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.counter-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 250;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}

#timer {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}

.clock-border {
  display: table;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.value {
  font-size: 200%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="countdown">
  <div id="countdown-overlay">
    <h1 class="counter-title"> Next stream in</h1>

    <div id="timer">
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">4 Days</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">7 Hours</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">3 Min</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-border">
        <p class="value">24 Sec</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>



</section>
```

Comment: This makes the image solid again removing the gradient behind it. Any way to counter this?

Comment: I've found some similar solutions, but all of which comes with side effects while your solution, if able to retain the gradient, does not.

Comment: @CodeSpent Another simple solution is to decrease the opacity of image in Photoshop :)

Comment: That was my very next thought, but wanted to see if a solution would be feasible in the styles first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: that does sort of bring me closer, and gives me a good idea of how to perfect it, but if I'm not mistaken its still ignoring the gradient entirely and just use the RGB value, which takes a bit away from what I'm going for. I believe I'm going to re-nest my content to allow the text to actually sit above the div and somehow position the overlay to fit without being necessarily wrapped, if that makes sense.